# vbscript: RegExp Replace turn capture group into variable

Tags: vbscript, regexp-replace, capture-group

regex in VBscript has 3 methods, Test, Extract and Replace, but I can only seem to turn capture groups from Extract into variable.
However what I want to do is use capturing groups from 'Replace' as a variable. I can get a Regex.Replace working with no problems using $1 $2 etc for capturing groups, however I want multiply one of the capture groups.

In an xml file, I want to extract a value, times it by 15, and insert it back in. In this example the  tag.

e.q.

```vb
strText = "
  <rte>
    <name>gpx.studio church 2 reduced.gpx</name>
    <rtept lat='-33.482652' lon='150.159134'>
      <ele>938.4</ele>
      <desc>076</desc>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat='-33.4825698175265' lon='150.159515440464'>
      <ele>942.3</ele>
      <desc>162</desc>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat='-33.4828785376496' lon='150.159633457661'>
      <ele>943.4</ele>
      <desc>098</desc>
    </rtept>
  </rte>
</gpx>"



Dim oRegExp
Set oRegExp = New RegExp
oRegExp.Global=True
oRegExp.Multiline = True
oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
strPattern = "(<rtept(?:(?:.|\n|\r)*?))<desc>(.*?)<\/desc>((?:(?:.|\n|\r)*?)<\/rtept>)"

strReplace = "$1<desc>$2<\/desc>$3"

' so on this line above, I want to turn the $2 into an integer and multiply it by 15 before putting back into replace. 
' I have not done it here because I know it doesnt work as  "$2"x1000

strNewText = oRegExp.Replace(strText, strReplace)
```

I want to turn the $2 into an integer and multiply it by 15 before putting back into replace.

I have tried to get the capture groups as SubMatches(1) which work with Regex.Extract method but it doesnt seem to work in Regex.Replace method, unless I am missing something....

help appreciated

Comment: Since you have structured data, why not use the **Microsoft.XMLDOM** object to directly access and change the data? Here's a [Simple Script](https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/blob/main/VBS-XML-Replace/gpx.vbs) that loads the XML data, multiplies each of the **desc** values by 15 and then saves the updated XML file. I have not posted it as an answer because the question was asking for a RegExp solution.

Comment: @LesFerch ah yes I see now my approach using regex is unnecessary. this is much cleaner. cheers :)